# how to get key of values for dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Dictionary<int, seq> compare = new Dictionary<int, seq>();
        compare.Add(1,new seq("x1",4));
        compare.Add(2,new seq("x2",1));
        compare.Add(3, new seq("x3", 2));
        compare.Add(4, new seq("x4", 3));          

    }
}
 class seq
 {

    private string Name;
    private int Random;
    public seq(string name,int rand)
    {            
        Name = name;
        Random = rand;
    }

}
```

For Random i want to get its key
Please help  me

Comment: It doesn't look like you've taken time to read about dictionary or perhaps google the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
int random = "the value you are looking for it's key";
var result = compare.Where(x=>x.Value.Random == random).Select(x=>x.Key);
```

However, we have to point out that the result would be general a sequence of `keys`, since the the same `random` value  may be included in many `seq` objects, that are contained in the dictionary called `compare`.

**If** you are sure that there is only one `seq` object for each `random` value you are looking for, then you have to change the above code to the following one:

```
var key =  compare.Where(x=>x.Value.Random == random).Select(x=>x.Key).Single();
```